# Setting a Python path in Windows XAMPP using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, xampp, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to use Python2.6 in combination with XAMPP1.7.3. But when I try to run my Apache server, it won't start. I went to my log files in and it told me this:

" httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 133 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/xampp/apache/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The specified module could not be found. "

It looks like Apache can't find the mod_wsgi.so file.

I have the XAMPP1.7.3 (32bit) and Python2.6 (32bit) version installed on my computer (Windows7 64 bit). I already checked if I could use this versions and normally it shouldn't give a problem.

This are the things I did:

1. I downloaded and installed XAMPP1.7.3 (32bit version)
2. I downloaded and installed Python2.6 (32bit version)
3. I tested the apache server on XAMPP and it worked, after that I shutted down XAMPP and rebooted my computer.
4. I downloaded the mod_wsgi file specifically for the combination of Apache2.2 and Python2.6
5. I putted the mod_wsgi file in C:\Xamp\Apache\modules
6. I added to following line to C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

   - LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
7. I tried to start Apache but it failed...

All suggestions welcome!

download path mod_wsgi: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DownloadTheSoftware?tm=2

Answer (score 0):

Double check that in the directory C:/xampp/apache/modules there exists a mod_wsgi.so and that there are no hidden extra extensions. If if it okay, then the error can mean you are missing DLLs required by mod_wsgi.

For the DLLs you need to have made sure you installed Python for all users and not just the user you installed it as. In worst case you may be missing compiler SDK libraries for compiler version used to build mod_wsgi.

Comment: I double checked that mod_wsgi.so is in C:\Xamp\Apache\modules, but next to the .so files there are 2 .dll files:
php5apache2_2.dll and php5apache2_2_filter.dll
 I don't know if they should be there or not?
Also I checked if there were hidden files but that is not the case.. And I gave all users of the PC full rights for using python, I really don't know what to do now..

Comment: Repeating what I said 'In worst case you may be missing compiler SDK libraries for compiler version used to build mod_wsgi.'. Use a DLL dependency checker to see if for mod_wsgi.so it can find everything it needs.